# How to Compare CHM Files

Tags: compare, diff, chm

I need to compare whether the given two CHM files are same or different..

What i have tried:

```
I have used GNU "Diff" utility.
It tells us a brief information that whether they are Same or Not.
```

Query:

```
How to check visually what are all the changes happened inside CHM files.
Is is possible to view it using any tool.
```

Answer (score 4):

I think FAR HTML is the tool you are looking for. You can use it some weeks for free. HH utilities is included.

This is useful for checking the differences between two Help files. A filter drop down list allows you to view files that are unique to one Help file etc.

You can simply select "File > Open and Compare" to open the second help file. 
Once the second Chm is opened, a new display panel becomes visible (see image below) and the file list displays files from both CHM's. Files from the second Chm are marked with a light blue background. The text box right of the filter drop down displays how many differences were found (this is the total from both CHM's).

[image]